How to get the binary content of a local variable like an image in the VSIX plugin when the debugger is in break mode?
I've created a VSIX plugin with a custom window, subscribed to the DebuggerEvents.OnEnterBreakMode event, and when the event occurs I try to access the _dte.Debugger.CurrentStackFrame.Locals.
But this list contains only a string Value property but no binary content and "real" data structure of the variable.
    [Guid("a3f215c7-f47d-4560-8d26-b2c4815a5929")]
    public class MyWindow : ToolWindowPane
    {
        public MyWindow() : base(null)
        {
            this.Caption = "MyWindow";
            this.Content = new MyWindowControl();           
        }
    }

    public partial class MyWindowControl : UserControl
    {
        private readonly DTE _dte;
    
        public MyWindowControl()
        {
            _dte = Package.GetGlobalService(typeof(DTE)) as DTE;            
            this.InitializeComponent();
            Loaded += MyWindowControl_Loaded;
        }
    
        private void MyWindowControl_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            _dte.Events.DebuggerEvents.OnEnterBreakMode -= DebuggerEvents_OnEnterBreakMode;
            _dte.Events.DebuggerEvents.OnEnterBreakMode += DebuggerEvents_OnEnterBreakMode;
        }
    
        private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            _dte.Events.DebuggerEvents.OnEnterBreakMode -= DebuggerEvents_OnEnterBreakMode;
            _dte.Events.DebuggerEvents.OnEnterBreakMode += DebuggerEvents_OnEnterBreakMode;
        }
    
        private void DebuggerEvents_OnEnterBreakMode(dbgEventReason Reason, ref dbgExecutionAction ExecutionAction)
        {
            if (_dte.Debugger.CurrentStackFrame == null) return;
    
            EnvDTE.Expressions locals = _dte.Debugger.CurrentStackFrame.Locals;
            foreach (EnvDTE.Expression local in locals)
            {
                var val = local.Value;
                // If the variable is of image type how can I access the data of the image to for example edit it or display it?
            }
        }       
    }

So my question is: if the variable is of image type how can I access the data of the image to for example edit it or display it?

Use an Image element

If the variable represents a path or a base64 encoded image, you can convert it back to an image object. For example "Convert.FromBase64String(your imageValue);"
